# MongoDB + NodeJS - Incrementing by a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using the native mongodb driver for nodejs and trying to increment a value in some documents by a variable in my nodejs program.

I have the below:

```
var foo = 2939.08
db.collection('mine').update({selected.col},{$inc:{bar:foo}},{upsert:true},function(err,doc){
    console.log(doc)
})
```

I am getting a null value written to my collection every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit**
Also my code looks closer to this

```
db.collection('mine').update({selected.col},{$set:{woo:top},$inc:{bar:foo}},{upsert:true},function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: Don't see that. This upserts and/or increments as expected. BTW `doc` as in the "document" is not the argument for the `update` callback, it actually returns the number of documents affected by the `update`

Comment: I'm sorry - I edited my code to show what I'm doing.  I am actually doing a $set operation as well as an $inc.

Comment: Still don't see the problem. What is the value of `woo`? What does null value written to collection mean? As long as `woo` has a value this works for me still.

Comment: I am trying to increment the 'bar' value by 'foo'.  the 'woo' is being populated by 'top' which is entering fine.

Comment: You are doing something different in your actual code to what you have posted then. The code you have posted works perfectly fine. Perhaps post your actual code or at least try a standalone listing to spot your problem.